# Cache expires on Redis before the TTL

Tags: redis, cache-expiration

I am using Redis in my application. I am caching the access token on redis with the expiration time as 2 weeks(1209600 seconds). But the token get delete in within 5-6 minutes.
I have monitored the same on redis terminal with TTL command. After expiring 600-700 seconds, the TTL command gives -2. I don't know how redis automatically deleting the data or expiring the cache before the expiration of TTL.
Can someone please help me here that is there any configuration which I need to change on redis server.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share how you're creating entries?  Also, I assume your server isn't at memory capacity.

Comment: On a high level, I am using following code to set the data in redis:
`@Autowired
RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

RedisConnection conn = connectionFactory.getConnection();
conn.expire("token", 1209600);` 

Also I used 'TTL token' command to keep on checking the remaining expiration time and suddenly after 10 min this command shows -2.

Comment: which memory capacity you are talking about. How can I see the default or current capacity and then how can i change the same.